# how to verify the validity of SSL certificate in an Android application

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I need to verify SSL certificate validity before making a service call. If certificate is not valid I need to show an alert. Please give me some idea on this.

Comment: What do you mean with "making a call", calling a method? O making a phone call? Maybe you can just patch the ssl and then make the http request https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Host name validation can be customizez by setting a custom `X509HostnameVerifier` on the `SSLSocketFactory`. Some implementations are already available in android: `AllowAllHostnameVerifier`, `BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier`, `StrictHostnameVerifier`
/* ... */

```
public class MyHostnameVerifier extends AbstractVerifier {
  boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
    X509Certificate[] chain = session.getPeerCertificateChain();
    /* made some checks... */
    return checked;
  }
}
sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(new MyHostnameVerifier());
```

Comment: In which place we should set sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier()?